# Integrating IoT device with Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google

I am currently working on a IoT device to control lights. This device is implemented using FreeRTOS.

I am little confused how to provide Google Home integration with this device, could someone shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Smart Home API](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/). The Google Assistant works with a webhook, sending commands to `SYNC`, `QUERY`, and `EXECUTE` on that URL. You will then need to send these commands to your device.

Setup happens through the Google Assistant app, where users must link with your OAuth server.

Here is [a sample project](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs) for Smart Home, using virtual devices.

Comment: I had read through the Smart Home API. From what I understand this requires us to have an existing cloud service that talks to our end devices that control our lights?

Comment: Yes you will need some sort of server to act as an intermediary with the Google Assistant. Your server should handle OAuth, process requests, and return responses to the Assistant.

Comment: Thank You for your response. This helped clarifying things a lot.