# Integrating IoT device with Amazon Alexa

Tags: api, connection, iot, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently working on a IoT device (Air Quality Monitor)
I am little confused how to provide Amazon Alexa integration with this device, could someone shed some light on this.?

I did make a Google Smart Home connection based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684403/integrating-iot-device-with-google-home) ask. Now i have a success connection with google home and i'm interesting to make a similar connection for Amazon Alexa and Apple Siri (if possible).

**Note: I not use Amazon Web Services!!**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: either implement your own [skill](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/ask-overviews/what-is-the-alexa-skills-kit.html), or use a predefined voice model that [Alexa Smart Home](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html) provides. The later should be faster, since you don't need to create your own voice model.